# Encoding Python Enum to JSON

Tags: python, json, enums, python-3.6

I have a dictionary where some of the keys are Enum instances (subclasses of enum.Enum). I am attempting to encode the dictionary into a JSON string using a custom JSON Encoder class as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder). All I want is to have the keys in the outputted JSON be the strings of the Enum names. For example `{ TestEnum.one : somevalue }` would be encoded to `{ "one" : somevalue }`.

I have written a simple test case, shown below, which I have tested in a clean virtualenv:

```
import json

from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    one = "first"
    two = "second"
    three = "third"

class TestEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ Custom encoder class """

    def default(self, obj):

        print("Default method called!")

        if isinstance(obj, TestEnum):
            print("Seen TestEnum!")
            return obj.name

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def encode_enum(obj):
    """ Custom encoder method """

    if isinstance(obj, TestEnum):
        return obj.name
    else:
        raise TypeError("Don't know how to decode this")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test = {TestEnum.one : "This",
            TestEnum.two : "should",
            TestEnum.three : "work!"}

    # Test dumps with Encoder method
    #print("Test with encoder method:")
    #result = json.dumps(test, default=encode_enum)
    #print(result)

    # Test dumps with Encoder Class
    print("Test with encoder class:")
    result = json.dumps(test, cls=TestEncoder)
    print(result)
```

I cannot successfully encode the dictionary (using Python 3.6.1). I continually get `TypeError: keys must be a string` errors and the default method of my custom encoder instance (supplied via the `cls` argument of the `json.dumps` method) never seems to be called? I have also attempted to supply a custom encoding method via the `default` argument of the `json.dumps` method, but again this is never triggered.

I have seen solutions involving the IntEnum class, but I need the values of the Enum to be strings. I have also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606049/json-encode-decode-gtk-enums) which discusses an issue related to an Enum which inherits from another class. However, my enums inherit from the base enum.Enum class only and correctly respond to `isinstance` calls?

Both the custom class and the method produce a `TypeError` when supplied to the `json.dumps` method. Typical output is shown below:

```
$ python3 enum_test.py

Test with encoder class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enum_test.py", line 59, in <module>
    result = json.dumps(test, cls=TestEncoder)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

I presume the issue is that the `encode` method of the JSONEncoder class assumes that it knows how to serialise the Enum class (because one of the if statements in the `iterencode` method is triggered) and so never calls the custom default methods and ends failing to serialise the Enum?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43730306/674039

Comment: You can't use anything other than strings for keys. The encoder doesn't get to intercede there, it's a hard rule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use anything but *strings* as keys in dictionaries you want to convert to JSON. The encoder doesn't give you any other options; the `default` hook is only called for values of unknown type, never for keys.

Convert your keys to strings up front:

```
def convert_keys(obj, convert=str):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [convert_keys(i, convert) for i in obj]
    if not isinstance(obj, dict):
        return obj
    return {convert(k): convert_keys(v, convert) for k, v in obj.items()}

json.dumps(convert_keys(test))
```

This recursively handles your dictionary keys. Note that I included a hook; you can then choose how to convert enumeration values to strings:

```
def enum_names(key):
    if isinstance(key, TestEnum):
        return key.name
    return str(key)

json.dumps(convert_keys(test, enum_names))
```

You can use the same function to reverse the process when loading from JSON:

```
def names_to_enum(key):
    try:
        return TestEnum[key]
    except KeyError:
        return key

convert_keys(json.loads(json_data), names_to_enum)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def enum_names(key):
...     if isinstance(key, TestEnum):
...         return key.name
...     return str(key)
...
>>> json_data = json.dumps(convert_keys(test, enum_names))
>>> json_data
'{"one": "This", "two": "should", "three": "work!"}'
>>> def names_to_enum(key):
...     try:
...         return TestEnum[key]
...     except KeyError:
...         return key
...
>>> convert_keys(json.loads(json_data), names_to_enum)
{<TestEnum.one: 'first'>: 'This', <TestEnum.two: 'second'>: 'should', <TestEnum.three: 'third'>: 'work!'}
```

Comment: Well that worked brilliantly! Thank you. It is shame there is not a way to do this via the Encoder and the docs are not as clear as they could be about this.

Comment: Great solution! Should be adopted into json.Encoder in some fashion.

Answer (score 17):

It is an old question. But no one gave this very simple answer.

You just need to subclass your Enum from str.

```
import json

from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(str, Enum):
    one = "first"
    two = "second"
    three = "third"

test = {TestEnum.one : "This",
        TestEnum.two : "should",
        TestEnum.three : "work!"}

print(json.dumps(test))
```

outputs:

```
{"first": "This", "second": "should", "third": "work!"}
```

Comment: waw, I love this one.

Answer (score 1):

I never use the builtin python enum anymore, I use a metaclass called "TypedEnum".

The reason is that the metaclass allows my string enums to act just like strings :  they can be passed to functions that take strings, they can be serialized as strings (just like you want... right in a JSON encoding), but they are still a strong type (isA Enum) too.

https://gist.github.com/earonesty/81e6c29fa4c54e9b67d9979ddbd8489d

The number of weird bugs I've run into with regular enums is uncountable.

```
class TypedEnum(type):
    """This metaclass creates an enumeration that preserve isinstance(element, type)."""

    def __new__(mcs, cls, _bases, classdict):
        """Discover the enum members by removing all intrinsics and specials."""
        object_attrs = set(dir(type(cls, (object,), {})))
        member_names = set(classdict.keys()) - object_attrs
        member_names = member_names - set(name for name in member_names if name.startswith('_') and name.endswith('_'))
        new_class = None
        base = None
        for attr in member_names:
            value = classdict[attr]
            if new_class is None:
                # base class for all members is the type of the value
                base = type(classdict[attr])
                new_class = super().__new__(mcs, cls, (base, ), classdict)
                setattr(new_class, "__member_names__", member_names)
            else:
                if not base == type(classdict[attr]):           # noqa
                    raise SyntaxError("Cannot mix types in TypedEnum")
            setattr(new_class, attr, new_class(value))

        return new_class

    def __call__(cls, arg):
        for name in cls.__member_names__:
            if arg == getattr(cls, name):
                return type.__call__(cls, arg)
        raise ValueError("Invalid value '%s' for %s" % (arg, cls.__name__))

    def __iter__(cls):
        """List all enum values."""
        return (getattr(cls, name) for name in cls.__member_names__)

    def __len__(cls):
        """Get number of enum values."""
        return len(cls.__member_names__)
```